# C# Accessing EXCEL, formatting cell as General

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, cell

When manipulating excel cells in C# (via an COM object), should I use the .Value or .Value2 ?
that is

```
 sheet.Cells[row + n, col].Value = "Hello world"
```

or

```
 sheet.Cells[row + n, col].Value2 = "Hello world"
```

What is the difference between them to ?

Also, how do I set a cell format to "General" ?

```
sheet.Cells[row + n, col].NumberFormat = "XYZ";  // Not sure what should be here
```

Right now when I assign a cell with the number "0,34" and even if I do

```
sheet.Cells[row + n, col].NumberFormat = "@";
```

I get this "little error" sign up in the left corner in each cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the first question you should read this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/09/06/225989.aspx

The optional parameters part doesn't apply anymore since C# 4.0 has optional parameters.

But there IS a difference (stated in the article)

> The only difference between this property [Value2] and the Value
>   property is that the Value2 property doesn’t use the Currency and Date
>   data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as
>   floating-point numbers by using the Double data type.

For the second question, have you tried setting a cell to 'General' and reading it out in code?

I think it's `sheet.Cells[row + n, col].NumberFormat = "General"`, where `"@"` is pure text.

Comment: Thanks for the article, I see now the difference, If I use "General" I get the error "The property NumberFormat can not be used on the class Range"

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the General type, as "magic string" that should to be assigned to the `NumberFormat` property try to use the empty string, e.g.

```
sheet.Cells[5, 7].NumberFormat = "";  // sets the cell type to the General type
```